# Прокси до api.telegram.org Apache2

Tags: linux, сеть, администрирование, telegram, apache2

Есть веб сервер на Apache2, который общается с телеграмом по api. Сегодня РКН прикрыл лавочку окончательно и теперь достучаться до туда не получится.

- Можно ли на апачах реализовать проксирование до определенного сайта?
- Как http resolver на Nginx, например?
- Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Можно.(10 символов). Если вы хотели услышать ответ на вопрос "как сделать....?" - стоит именно так и задавать вопрос.

Comment: Прошу прощения, писал в попыхах. Не поделитесь статьей или мануалом?

Comment: Под Apache вы понимаете Apache или код на Python\php\..... ? если первое - ничем не помогу, кроме направления поиска -> vpn\proxy\iptables+vpn\proxy + **Что такое Apache**
Если второе -> то vpn\proxy =)

Comment: откуда куда и через что вам надо «достучаться»? внесите, пожалуйста, правки в вопрос, нажав [edit]

Comment: а зачем тут айпитаблес? Вам нужен прокси сервер за границей. если это хттп прокси, то делайте запрос на ip этого сервера с передачей заголовка Host.